# Extract specific word and the value after it from text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, extract, cpu-word

I have the input file as:

```
1 sentences, 6 words, 1 OOVs
1 zeroprobs, logprob= -21.0085 ppl= 15911.4 ppl1= 178704
6 words, rank1= 0 rank5= 0 rank10= 0
7 words+sents, rank1wSent= 0 rank5wSent= 0 rank10wSent= 0 qloss= 0.925606 absloss= 0.856944

file input.txt : 1 sentences, 6 words, 1 OOVs
1 zeroprobs, logprob= -21.0085 ppl= 15911.4 ppl1= 178704
6 words, rank1= 0 rank5= 0 rank10= 0
7 words+sents, rank1wSent= 0 rank5wSent= 0 rank10wSent= 0 qloss= 0.925606 absloss= 0.856944
```

I want to extract the word ppl and the value coming after it, in this case: ppl=15911.4

I am using this code:

```
with open("input.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
       for part in line.split():
          if "ppl=" in part:
              print part
```

However this is only extracting the word ppl but not the value. I would also like to print the file name along.

Expected Output:

```
input.txt, ppl=15911.4
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That's because you're splitting by a space. The value of `ppl` will be the next element in the list. If modifying the file is an option, consider removing the space after the equal signs.

Comment: The problem is I have a folder full of files in this format and I can't modify the input file :(

Comment: One way is to read the file into a string and then match the regular expression `/\b(?<=ppl= )\d+\.\d/`. `\b` is a *word break* and `(?<=ppl= )` is a *positive lookbehind* that asserts that the match is immediately preceded by `"ppl= "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix it by using a simple counter:

```
found = False
with open("input.txt") as openfile:
     for line in openfile:
         if not found:
             counter = 0
             for part in line.split():
                  counter = counter + 1
                  if "ppl=" in part:
                      print part
                      print line.split()[counter]
                      found = True
```

Comment: It is printing twice due to the presence of the word twice :( How to make it print only once.

Answer (score 6):

You may use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) function,

```
with open("input.txt") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
       s = line.split()
       for i,j in enumerate(s):
          if j == "ppl=":
              print s[i],s[i+1]
```

Example:

```
>>> fil = '''1 zeroprobs, logprob= -21.0085 ppl= 15911.4 ppl1= 178704
6 words, rank1= 0 rank5= 0 rank10= 0'''.splitlines()
>>> for line in fil:
        s = line.split()
        for i,j in enumerate(s):
            if j == "ppl=":
                print s[i],s[i+1]


ppl= 15911.4
>>>
```

To print only the first value,

```
>>> for line in fil:
        s = line.split()
        for i,j in enumerate(s):
            if j == "ppl=":
                print s[i],s[i+1]
        break

ppl= 15911.4
```

Comment: twice??, how... Is there any other string with the exact name `ppl=` ?

Comment: Oops! Yes, the word and value is repeating. I will post the full file. Sorry for my mistake. One sec.

Comment: It is not printing anything after using break :(

Comment: any error? How it's possible? Note that you need to add the `break` stmt for first `for` loop not for the second one.

Comment: I don't know it is not working :( Maybe inputting the file is a problem. I will check it out :) However, I got the output. Thanks a lot for ur time and ideas. It helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the list generated from `line.split()` to a variable, then use a while loop with i as a counter to iterate through and when you hit 'ppl=' you can return 'ppl=' and the next index

```
with open("input.txt") as openfile:
for line in openfile:
    phrases = line.split()
    i = 0
    while i < len(phrases):
        if 'ppl=' in phrases[i]
            print "ppl= " + str(phrases[i + 1])
        i += 1
```